# Possible to load pdf files by SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, file, pdf

I am wondering whether its possible to load contents of pdf files using SQL Queries? 
My goal is to get all metadata stored inside a Pdf file which is located on another server.

Does sql have this functionality?

Comment: what kind of metadata?

Comment: The target pdf files contains some meta data inside them. In PDF properties users can provide some info like title, author, description, keywords, etc.
I want to somehow retrieve these details

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a language for manipulating data in tables. Most (all?) implementation of SQL do not provide an adaptor for reading the metadata in PDF files. The answer to your question is No.

So your problem is better restated: is there a way to extract PDF metadata into a tabular form that could be accessed by SQL? The answer to this is Yes, but there are many choices and you have some research to do. So:

1. Learn about metadata and decide what kind you want.
2. Find or write a tool to extract it.
3. Format the data in such a way that SQL can manipulate it.

Start with the Adobe site: http://www.adobe.com/digitalimag/pdfs/about_metadata.pdf
Try this too: http://meta-extractor.sourceforge.net/